# How to iterate over files containing space in FreeBSD /bin/sh

Tags: sh, freebsd

I am trying to actuate over a set of files that contain space using FreeBSD /bin/sh shell:

```
user@host:~/temp/2011 $ find . | grep '03-11'
./01jan/ES 03-11.txt
./02feb/ES 03-11.txt
./03mar/ES 03-11.txt
./04apr/ES 03-11.txt
./05may/ES 03-11.txt
user@host:~/temp/2011 $ for i in `find . | grep '03-11'`; do echo "$i"; done
./01jan/ES
03-11.txt
./02feb/ES
03-11.txt
./03mar/ES
03-11.txt
./04apr/ES
03-11.txt
./05may/ES
03-11.txt
```

While I would like to get:

```
user@host:~/temp/2011 $ find . | grep '03-11'
./01jan/ES 03-11.txt
./02feb/ES 03-11.txt
./03mar/ES 03-11.txt
./04apr/ES 03-11.txt
./05may/ES 03-11.txt
user@host:~/temp/2011 $ for i in `find . | grep '03-11'`; do echo "$i"; done
./01jan/ES 03-11.txt
./02feb/ES 03-11.txt
./03mar/ES 03-11.txt
./04apr/ES 03-11.txt
./05may/ES 03-11.txt
```

What shall be done to deal with the space in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `IFS` to a value that does not include a space character.

For example:

```
(IFS=$'\n'; for i in `find . | grep '03-11'`; do echo "$i"; done)
```

See the [manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Some would fight hard for [*"the canonical Unix way of doing these kinds of things"*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365838/pipe-to-mv-command/365848#365848)

```sh
find . -type f | grep '03-11' | xargs -I {} echo {}
```

Comment: For some unknown reason I have never used `xargs` despite everytime I see it I think "this is a very useful command"

Comment: BTW, FreeBSD implementation of xargs does not support `-d\n`